Why does transformer insulation resistance decrease when filled with insulating oil?
This question was asked by someone: "It turns out that this is normal, so what is the reason for this?"
After repair of a transformer, it was shipped overseas without insulating oil. Prior to that, insulation resistance tests and insulation power factor test was conducted at reduced voltage of 1 kV. Before shipment, all insulation tests yielded a value of about 5 GΩ between windings and windings to ground. Insulation power factor was below 1%. Upon arrival atthe  site, unit was vacuum filled with oil and electrical tests were conducted.
The insulation resistance dropped to about 0.5 GΩ for all tests while the insulation power factor remains almost the same. The oil was tested for moisture content and DBV and yielded 19 ppm and 76 kV/mm. We drained the oil and conducted the same tests again - the values measured were like before the unit was oil-filled.

What conductivity would you expect from oil with a water content of 19 ppm? It not dry! Does the transformer have a specified effective internal geometry to combine with that oil conductivity to yield an expected resistance?

Many dielectric liquids in-situ conduct better than dry air would, because they have absorbed moisture and other contaminants. That is the reason for your observation, and it's to be expected. The bulk conductance is a minor factor, since the benefit of the liquid is to vastly increase the breakdown voltage. That it conducts somewhat better than air may matter or may not - it's still a pretty good dielectric, as you've measured.
Ionic contaminants and most importantly water content play a big role in effective conductance of insulating oils. To get best results, the device (e.g. a transformer) has to be purged with a warm, dry, inert gas long enough to get rid of all residual moisture first - this has to be done while measuring the absolute moisture content of exhaust gas, and continued until the measurement is similar to the intake gas. Then an oil source needs to be opened, while maintaining the gas purge. The oil moisture content has to be measured to be within allowable range ahead of adding it to the transformer. Conductance and ionic contamination also has to be checked to prevent contaminating the much more expensive transformer. This whole procedure is not always needed, but to get the best process contamination control you have to do it, otherwise you'll be "fighting with ghosts", unable to say where the problem originated. Ultimately you either measure it or you're in the dark.
In your case, 19ppm moisture content in the oil seems to be OK but definitely could be improved. Heating up the oil to above 100C with a dry gas purge for a day or two will lower the moisture content. There are other ways to lower the moisture content as well - ask the oil manufacturer for what they recommend.
I've been dealing mostly with old and unique or not economically replaceable equipment where the oil had to be decontaminated and reused in situ due to very costs that would be incurred otherwise.

The insulation resistance measured in the tests depends on the DC fluid resistivity. It is like measuring the resistance between two electrodes, but isn't that easy as we can guess, due to polarization effects (https://d-nb.info/1069539759/34).
Oil has much better insulating properties than air. However, this statement is regarding DC and AC dielectric breakdown and not about resistivity itself. If you look for resistivity values, both oil and air will "by catalogue" present something like \$?\times10^{-13}\$. It means that they are very good insulators, but not perfect. Furthermore, if you search for, you will also note that the conductivity depends on many parameters, as contamination (due to water or other materials) and temperature (the dependence on temperature is different between oil and air).
Additionally, you didn't mention which one is the case of your transformer, but it also varies considerably between mineral and vegetal (ester) liquids.
Another factor is the impregnation time (the period one waits after filling the transformer with oil). Surface resistivity plays a role in this measurement and if the oil doesn't have the time to impregnate insulation (especially for esters), it can affect your measurements.
In summary, it's not because oil is "better" than air for transformer that it will present lower insulation resistivity.
